# How do I switch to strings.xml while using dynamic arrays?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to switch to strings.xml to allow for multiple languages.
I know how to load a string array from the strings.xml and for simple arrays that is not a problem, but most of my arrays are not simple! The whole idea is to spider them.

```
fun pick( list :Array<String>):String{
    return list.random()
}

fun colour():String {
    val list = arrayOf("blue","red","green",size()+"")
    return pick(list)
}

fun size():String {
    val list = arrayOf("big","small","medium")
    return pick(list)
}
```

above is a quick example 
the size function would work fine from strings.xml but the colour function would not as part of the array is dynamically chosen when the function is hit

The reason it all goes through pick() is to allow me to add modifiers to the strings (changing the colour, counting how many times the function is called etc)

Some of the arrays in my actual code (which is c# at the moment) have 10 or 20 dynamic entries

So how do we use strings.xml for this? is there a way to perhaps add keywords I can then change in pick()....though then pick would essentially be calling itself?

I have been stuck on this for days maybe I am missing something obvious?

EDIT

Tried using keywords but it causes a stack overflow, example code:

```
fun keyword(input:String):String{
    val result = input.replace(
        "#colour", colour()
    ).replace(
        "#size", size()
    )
    return result
}

fun pick( list :Array<String>):String{
    val tempResult = list.random()
    val result= keyword(tempResult)
    return result
}

fun colour():String {
    val list = arrayOf("blue","red","green","#size blue")
    return pick(list)
}

fun size():String {
    val list = arrayOf("big","small","medium")
    return pick(list)
}

fun example():String{
    val list = arrayOf("#size #colour whale")
    return pick(list)
}
```

this was called with
    val result = example()
(well essentially that, the calling is being done async so that wen the arrays get large they will not hang up the program, tested with out the keywords and it works fine)

error is:

> 2019-04-17 22:48:41.433 9010-9665/com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper
>   W/System.err: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1041KB
>   2019-04-17 22:48:41.436 9010-9665/com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper
>   W/System.err:     at java.util.Random.next(Random.java:202) 2019-04-17
>   22:48:41.436 9010-9665/com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper W/System.err:
>   at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:390) 2019-04-17 22:48:41.436
>   9010-9665/com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper W/System.err:     at
>   kotlin.random.AbstractPlatformRandom.nextInt(PlatformRandom.kt:45)
>   2019-04-17 22:48:41.436 9010-9665/com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper
>   W/System.err:     at
>   kotlin.random.Random$Default.nextInt(Random.kt:246) 2019-04-17
>   22:48:41.436 9010-9665/com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper W/System.err:
>   at kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt.random(_Arrays.kt:2212)
>   2019-04-17 22:48:41.437 9010-9665/com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper.GeneratorFragment.pick(GeneratorFragment.kt:129)
>   2019-04-17 22:48:41.437 9010-9665/com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper.GeneratorFragment.colour(GeneratorFragment.kt:136) 2019-04-17 22:48:41.437 9010-9665/com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.mrgreaper2004.dmslittlehelper.GeneratorFragment.keyword(GeneratorFragment.kt:121)

the last parts of the error just repeat

Answer (score 0):

well i sussed it!

```
fun pick( list :Array<String>):String{
    val tempResult = list.random()
    //val result= keyword(tempResult)
    return tempResult
}

fun colour():String {
    val list = arrayOf("blue","red","green","#size blue")
    val tresult=pick(list)
    val result = tresult.replace("#size",size())
    return result
}

fun size():String {
    val list = arrayOf("big","small","medium")
    val result=pick(list)
    return result
}

fun example():String{
    val list = arrayOf("#size #colour whale")
    val tresult=pick(list)
    val result = tresult.replace("#size",size()).replace("#colour",colour())
    return result
}
```

since not every generator will use every generator I can choose to be specific... the answer suddenly came to me as I often use a string in an array to replace multiple calls of the same function.... for example if an array had multiple different items each with a chance of a colour but only one item would be picked I chose a random colour assigned it to a string and then reference it in each item that needed a colour...no sense randomly picking multiple colours if just one would be used (may be bad at explaining)

Comment: I am aware that the code can be streamlined...a lot. this was just a quick way to test